# How to create robot.txt in godaddy sharing server with multiple domains

Tags: php, html, robots.txt, googlebot

Good afternoon, I hope you can help me, I have a question:

I have a server with godaddy (delux-sharing), on this server I have the following:

/ 
--/mail
--/etc
--/public_html
----/web1
----/web2
------/index.php
------/css
------/img
------/js
----/web3
--/tmp

I am creating a robot.txt file in which I want NO indexing anything in web2, refieron me with nothing to everything (index.html, css, img, js), but YES want to index the other pages (web1, web3) how can I accomplish this? robot.txt file in that folder have to go? in /, /public_html, /web2?

I could help with the file contents: robot.txt?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The file must be named `robots.txt`, not `robot.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll use two different robots.txt files. One goes into /web1 and the other goes into /web2. As far as crawlers go, if /web1 is the root of 'somedomain.com' they will not be able to crawl up a folder and on to the /web2 folder (or any other folder on the same level).

**Edit:** Some sample robots.txt files

**To exclude all robots from the entire server** (where "server" == "domain")

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

**To allow all robots complete access**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

(or just create an empty "/robots.txt" file, or don't use one at all)

**To exclude all robots from part of the server**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /junk/
```

**To exclude a single robot**

```
User-agent: BadBot
Disallow: /
```

**To allow a single robot**

```
User-agent: Google
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

---

So, `/web2` would get a robots.txt file with:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

and `/web1` and `/web3` would get empty robot.txt files or

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Comment: Ok then I put a robot.txt file in each folder? Each folder corresponds to a domain, but I want to know the contents of the file robot.txt

Answer (score 2):

Each folder corresponds to a domain, and if you need to disable indexing of www.web2.com then you need to create robots.txt and locate it in /web2

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Adding robots.txt to web1, web3 (for other domains) is optional. 
You could put there following content

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Once done you could validate your robots.txt e.g. at http://www.frobee.com/robots-txt-check

Also to block a search engine to index you could include following meta-tag directly in html

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```